# Why are numbers and special characters inserted into spaces?

Tags: c++, input, getline

I've been trying to use getline to recognize the spaces in my string input. Instead of spaces, numbers are special characters are being inserted between words. When I use cin normally the function works, but it doesn't see spaces.

How can I change the following so that there are actual spaces?

Here's my code with getline(Letters in string no longer shifting):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void encrypt(std::string &iostr, int key)
{
    key %= 26;
    int ch;

    for (auto &it : iostr)
    {
        ch = tolower(it) + key;
        if (ch > 'z')
            ch -= 26;
        it = ch;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string source;
    int key = 1;
    cout << "Paste cyphertext and press enter to shift 1 right: ";

    getline(cin, source);
    encrypt(source, key);


    cout << source << "";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `encrypt` inserts special characters is that the loop does not pay attention to spaces, shifting them by `key` code points in the same way as it does the regular characters.

Adding a check to see if the character is a lowercase letter will fix the problem:

```
for (auto &it : iostr)
{
    ch = tolower(it);
    if (!islower(ch)) {
        continue;
    }
    ch += key;
    if (ch > 'z') {
        ch -= 26;
    }
    it = ch;
}
```

Comment: why not `if (isspace(ch)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver This would keep other characters, such as digits and special characters. However, OP's shifting algorithm is not suitable for these characters.

Comment: Works perfectly. I'll remember that check. Thank you very much dasblinkenlight.

Comment: Ah I see.  You are only going to encrypt the character if it is in a-z.

Answer (score 0):

You are shifting all characters by the key including the spaces. You need to exclude the spaces from your shift if you want them to stay. For example you could do the following:

```
void encrypt(std::string &iostr, int key)
{
   key %= 26;
   int ch;

   for (auto &it : iostr)
   {
      if (it != ' ')  //if not space character then shift
      {
         ch = tolower(it) + key;
         if (ch > 'z')
            ch -= 26;
         it = ch;
      }
   }
}
```